# Sync data from staging to production?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have staging and production instances  of my django app running, each with its own db.

I want to load data in staging first, check its correctness and then push it to the production db / instance.

What would be the best way to push from a staging instance to the production instance?

Thanks

Comment: What db do you use on dev and pro?

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have left that out.  MySQL on both.

Comment: simply dump and import (LOAD DATA INFILE)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're having MySQL on both, it can be done rather easily.

You need to dump the db from staging after the data is checked and then add the dump to your repo, so that it can be pulled to production.

If you want to automatically update the dump each time you make some changes and commit them try to use [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). Usage of the pre-commit hook script for dumping the dp to repo and the post-merge hook for its restoring should do the trick.

Comment: yeap, hope this'll help.